# Plugin for integrating SQLMAP and BURP SUITE

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I am trying to do SQL Injection using the SQLMAP Burp Plugin which I downloaded from  http://code.google.com/p/gason/downloads/list. I have followed the steps for windows provided in  http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/sqlmap-burp-plugin-2/.
But when I am running the command provided, I am getting an error like:

```
Could not find or load main class "-classpath"
```

I have tried replacing the classpath with the path of the plugin, but this didn't help. Can someone please help me solve this thing? This is for Windows 7.

Comment: This strikes me as a programming question, shouldn't it be posted in stackoverflow instead?

Comment: There's a double dash: --classpath

Comment: No it didn't work...Its single

Comment: Sai - I see most of your questions have been closed. Please familiarise yourself with our [about] and [ask] pages to ensure you are asking well structured, on-topic questions.

Answer (score 0):

Is single dash. Anyway, be sure of change the burp version to yours. So, in the example of the link you put, the command is: `Java –classpath burpplugins.jar:”burpsuite_v1.4.0.1.jar” burp.StartBurp` . In my case, is Linux, the **J**ava must be in lowercase **java**, not your case because you are using windows which is case insensitive for this... and my command is `java -classpath burpplugins.jar:”burpsuite_v1.7.0.3.jar” burp.StartBurp` but the point is you must unzip the files in the same folder as burp is.

Anyway, the plugin doesn't contribute too much in my opinion. You can save into a file (from burp) the http request you need and then you can use sqlmap instead with `-u`parameter to specify a URL using a `-r`to specify the file with the http request you want to use and is the same.